# Group by a column and creat a new data frame using bash

Tags: bash, dataframe, awk

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
chr1,A,1,3,y,-
chr1,A,2,30,y,-
chr1,A,12,40,y,-
chr2,B,0,3,y,-
chr2,B,1,30,y,-
chr3,C,1,3,y,-
```

I want to group by the 2nd column and then take the min value from the 3rd column and the max value from the 4th column using bash. so the desired output should be as:

```
chr1,A,1,40,y,-
chr2,B,0,30,y,-
chr3,C,1,3,y,-
```

I managed to build a crude code to do it but it does not completely give the final output.

Here is the code :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {if (!( $2 in min )) { min[$2] = $3; max[$2] = $4; row[$2] = $0 } else { if ($3 < min[$2]) min[$2] = $3; if ($4 > max[$2]) max[$2] = $4; row[$2] = $0 } } END { for (key in row) print row[key] }'
```

and the final output that I get with this code is:

```
chr1,A,2,30,y,-
chr2,B,1,30,y,-
chr3,C,1,3,y,-
```

How can I get the output I want? Is there any simpler code that can do this in bash? Thank you.

Comment: Are the other columns (5th and 6th in your example) guaranteed to be identical for all unique 3nd column values? If not, which values do you want printed - first, last, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```bash
$ <ip.txt datamash -t, -g1,2 min 3 max 4 first 5-6
chr1,A,1,40,y,-
chr2,B,0,30,y,-
chr3,C,1,3,y,-
```

- `-t,` use `,` as the field separator
- `-g1,2` group by first and second columns (assuming they'll always be the same as shown in the sample)
- `min 3` get the minimum value of third column
- `max 4` get the maximum value of fourth column
- `first 5-6` for the final two columns, just use the first instance

Comment: Excellent (and up-voted). It reminds me that I should definitely have a look at `datamash`.

Comment: This is amazing thank you for introducing the ```datamash```.

Comment: Does this tool support CSV format? It's excellent.

Comment: @konsolebox not as far as I know, you can check out https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv instead

Answer (score 2):

Your solution does not work because you store the **unmodified** lines in array `row` with the second field as key. So, printing the content of `row` in the `END` block just prints the last encountered line with that key, with whatever third and fourth fields it had, instead of the min and max you computed for that key.

Here is a variant of yours that constantly updates the third and fourth fields of a line with the current min and max for the key, **before** storing it in the `row` array.

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
!($2 in row) { min[$2] = $3; max[$2] = $4; row[$2] = $0; next }
$3 < min[$2] { min[$2] = $3 }
$4 > max[$2] { max[$2] = $4 }
{ $3 = min[$2]; $4 = max[$2]; row[$2] = $0 }
END { for(key in row) print row[key] }' foo.txt
```

Or, if the original order matters:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
!($2 in row) { key[++n] = $2; min[$2] = $3; max[$2] = $4; row[$2] = $0; next }
$3 < min[$2] { min[$2] = $3 }
$4 > max[$2] { max[$2] = $4 }
{ $3 = min[$2]; $4 = max[$2]; row[$2] = $0 }
END { for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) print row[key[i]] }' foo.txt
```

Note: if your input is already grouped by the second field, as in your example, we can use the same principle but with scalars instead of arrays (less memory usage) and print the outputs on the fly (more reactive):

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
NR > 1 && $2 != key { print row }
NR == 1 || $2 != key { key = $2 ; min = $3; max = $4; row = $0; next }
$3 < min { min = $3 }
$4 > max { max = $4 }
{ $3 = min; $4 = max; row = $0 }
END { print row }' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
$2 != prev { prt(); prev=$2 }
min > $3 { min = $3 }
max < $4 { max = $4 }
END { prt() }

function prt(   orig) {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        orig = $0
        $0 = line
        $3 = min
        $4 = max
        print
        $0 = orig
    }
    line = $0
    min  = $3
    max  = $4
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
chr1,A,1,40,y,-
chr2,B,0,30,y,-
chr3,C,1,3,y,-
```

Note that unlike the solutions that produce output from a loop in an `END` block, the above does not store all of the input in memory, just the current set of lines for each unique $2 value at a time, so it'll work for arbitrarily large input files but that means your input does have to be grouped on $2 values as shown in your example. If it isn't then just run `sort -t, -k2,2` on it before the awk script.

It'll also produce output lines in the same order as the input lines, if that matters, which would not be guaranteed to be true for any solution that does `for (i in whatever)` to produce output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming fields 1, 2, 5 and 6 are unique:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    { k = $1 FS $2 FS $5 FS $6 }
    !seen[k]++ {
        keys[key_count++] = k
        fields[k, 1] = $1; fields[k, 2] = $2; fields[k, 5] = $5; fields[k, 6] = $6
        min[k] = $3; max[k] = $4
        next
    }
    { min[k] = $3 < min[k] ? $3 : min[k]; max[k] = $4 > max[k] ? $4 : max[k] }
    END {
        for (j = 0; j < key_count; ++j) {
            k = keys[j]
            print fields[k, 1], fields[k, 2], min[k], max[k], fields[k, 5], fields[k, 6]
        }
    }' file
```

Output:

```
chr1,A,1,40,y,-
chr2,B,0,30,y,-
chr3,C,1,3,y,-
```

There are many issues in your code including not initializing min and max values for a specific "key".

Answer (score 1):

uses all the fields except min/max for grouping and in case the data is not consistent you'll notice in the output instead of ignoring it. Loses the original record order, but perhaps can be recovered by sorting on the desired field.

```
awk -F,           ' {k=$1 FS $2 FS SUBSEP FS $5 FS $6} 
        !(k in min) {min[k]=$3; max[k]=$3} 
          $3<min[k] {min[k]=$3} 
          $4>max[k] {max[k]=$4} 
                END {for(k in min) 
                      {sub(SUBSEP, min[k] FS max[k], k); print k}}' file | sort

chr1,A,1,40,y,-                                                                                                                              
chr2,B,0,30,y,-                                                                                                                              
chr3,C,1,3,y,-
```

Comment: That would be fine if the values in $3 and $4 cannot contain `&`s but if they can then that `sub(...)` would fail cryptically.